# How to rewrite column from oracle to infromix

Tags: oracle, informix

In oracle I have defined column like this:

```
column_name varchar2(1024 char)
```

how should I rewrite it to informix db ?

Comment: are you sure ? When what is the different between varchar2(1024) and varchar2(1024 char)

Comment: See here for a description of the difference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50977

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name man I know this but I mean different between varchar2(1024) and varchar2(1024 char) when you rewriting to informix. PS: U can defined column varchar(1024) in informix max value is just 255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `VARCHAR` Infomix type is limited to 255 chars I would use `LVARCHAR` type which is limited to 32,739 bytes.

The 2nd problem is `(1024 char)` which means that Oracle can save 1024 chars. In encoding like UTF-8 this is not equal to 1024 bytes. For example Polish letters: ąęćŃŻŚ are saved with 2 bytes so text with 1024 Polish letters will use 2048 bytes.

Informix uses bytes length so you must know your encoding and data. For Polish text in UTF8 encoding I would translate `varchar2(1024 char)` into `lvarchar(2048)`.

Comment: lvarchar2 ? I dont know this type probably you mean lvarchar. Anyway your answer seems ok

Comment: Just one addtional question. Why you prefer lvarchar instead of NVARCHAR ?

Comment: `lvarchar2` was just a typo :-)

Comment: `NVARCHAR` is both in Oracle and Informix. AFAIK in Informix `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` differ mainly in collation but both have limitation to 255 bytes.

Comment: ah ok thx a lot. Anyway could help me with another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476263/how-to-rewrite-column-raw18-to-informix ?