# How to rewrite column raw(18) to informix

Tags: oracle, informix

in my application I have oracle column:

COLUMN_NAME  RAW(18)              not null

How should I rewrite it to informix ? I found that similar type is byte but I need also create index on this column which is not allowed on byte (in oracle on raw it is possible)

Comment: And what is the content of that field?

Comment: How do you index this column on Oracle? Is it based on some metadata, for example EXIF from JPEG file?

Comment: @juergend Why it is important to know ? Just some uuid in byte form

Comment: @MichałNiklas I dont know how it oracle index. I just know that I can create index on raw column

Comment: OK, if it is uuid than it is possible to make some index. How do you INSERT/UPDATE data into that column?

Comment: @MichałNiklas in oracle I can do this: Insert into REQUEST (ID,UUID) values (7829,'BBB00E6B5DCF4C049395062C55390D34');

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing are you working with version 12.10 of Informix.
This is little weird since at version 11.70 I'm able to use this same command without need to register the datablade.

Anyway, try this :

```
execute function SYSBldPrepare('binaryudt.*','create');

(expression)

           0

1 row(s) retrieved.


CREATE TABLE  bindata_test (int_col integer, bin_col binaryvar) ;
Table created.
```

At the `onstat -m` (or `select * from sysmaster:sysonlinelog order by offset desc`) you should see a message like this :

```
11:56:57  Unloading Module <$INFORMIXDIR/extend/ifxmngr/ifxmngr.bld>
11:56:57  The C Language Module <$INFORMIXDIR/extend/ifxmngr/ifxmngr.bld> unloaded
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems that you store bytes in this columns. Those bytes create UUID and in code you use bytes encoded in hexadecimal.

To store such data I would use `VARCHAR(36)`. In hex encoding you need two chars for each byte so I used 36 as length (18 * 2).

In this solution your INSERT do not change. SELECT probably also do not change. Indexing is easy and works. For SELECT results you will have to decode hex string into bytes. You can do in in application code, or use stored function.

With other datatype like `BYTE` indexing may not work. I am also not sure if all drivers (JDBC, ODBC) can use text literal in SQL statements (INSERT/SELECT etc). Some drivers must use PreparedStatement with binary type.

Comment: there isnt better solution ? I want to avoid this solution because then I should also rewrite my app. Where I have byte[] I need to rewrite it to String and add conversion between byte and string in my app

Comment: But your INSERT uses string literal, so at least half of work is done. As for SELECT results you will have to decode hex string into bytes. You can do in in application code, or use stored function.

Comment: ok and when I dont need to index column just put there some uuid, still is better options to user varchar instead of byte ?

Comment: If you use `byte` then you probably will have to use PreparedStatement for each INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT. See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483284/consistent-method-of-inserting-text-column-to-informix-database-using-jdbc-and-o . It is about other Informix blob type, but problem with string literals for binary types is similar.

Comment: btw when I must use varchar for raw(18) I will prefer varchar(24) and store it as base64 value not as hex with lenght 36 to save some space

Comment: Of course you can encode it using base64 but from your comment it seems that you already use hex encoding. If it is not huge database then I would prefer already working string representation.

Answer (score 0):

I found in new version of Informix data type: binaryvar and binary18: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.dbext.doc%2Fids_dbxt_386.htm  I dont try it yet but I think raw(18) should be replace byt these data types

But I dont know how to create table with with column. When I try:

```
CREATE TABLE  bindata_test (int_col integer, bin_col binaryvar)
```

it return error:

```
Type (binaryvar) not found.
```

My database is logged and `SELECT name,is_ansi FROM sysmaster:sysdatabases` return 0 so it should work

Comment: this is not an answer... please edit your answer including this information with a "EDIT" text before to make clear you have add information later...